# Run timecomplexity of this code (karatsuba)

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, karatsuba

Can you please provide the time-complexity of this karatsuba algorithm which is run on 2 n-bit long numbers:

```
function karatsuba(num1, num2)

      if (num1 < 10) or (num2 < 10)
        return num1*num2

      /* calculates the size of the numbers */
      m = max(size_base10(num1), size_base10(num2))
      m2 = m/2

      /* split the digit sequences about the middle */
      high1, low1 = split_at(num1, m2)
      high2, low2 = split_at(num2, m2)

      /* 3 calls made to numbers approximately half the size */
      z0 = karatsuba(low1,low2)
      z1 = karatsuba((low1+high1),(low2+high2))
      z2 = karatsuba(high1,high2)

      return (z2*10^(2*m2))+((z1-z2-z0)*10^(m2))+(z0)
```

Comment: This code is from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm which also [gives the complexity with analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm#Efficiency_analysis).

Comment: depends on `size_base10` implementation and outer bound for `n` ... meaning if basic datatypes are used or arbitrary precision ... so the answer varies a lot ... for example `size_base10` might be `O(1)` ,  `O(log(n))` or even much much worse like `O(log^2(n))` or worse and that is just the init ... the same goes for `split_at` ... so how are your numbers represented and what are the bounds? without it you can not determine big O...